# How to extract exact match from list of strings in Python into separate lists

Tags: python, regex

This is an example list of strings

```
new_text = ['XIC(Switch_A)OTE(Light1) XIC(Light1)OTE(Light2) Motor On Delay Timer XIC(Light1)TON(Motor_timer',
 '?',
 '?) XIC(Motor_timer.DN)OTE(Motor)']
```

I would like to extract `XIC(Switch_A)` into one list, `OTE(Light1)` into another list, `TON(Motor_timer)` into another list and so on.

This is the code in Python 3 that I have tried

```
for words in new_text:
    match = re.search('XIC(.*)', words)
print(match.group(1))
```

How do I go about extracting `OTE(Tag name)`, `XIC(Tag name)`, `XIO(Tag name)` into their own lists or groups?

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of identifiers (`OTE`, `XIC`, `XIO`, etc) or do you want to match `<any three letters>(<something>)`?

Comment: I have a list of identifiers. mainly XIC, XIO, OTE, TON, TOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match *any three uppercase letters*, followed by anything in parentheses:

```
([A-Z]{3})(\([^)]+\))
(        )             : Capturing group 1
          (         )  : Capturing group 2
 [A-Z]{3}              : Exactly three uppercase letters
           \(     \)   : Literal open/close parentheses
             [^)]+     : One or more of any character that is not )
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/d1JCcf/1)

Use a `collections.defaultdict` to keep track of all your results. The identifier will be the key for this defaultdict, and the values will be lists containing all the matches for that identifier.

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(list)

regex = re.compile(r"([A-Z]{3})(\([^)]+\))")

for s in new_text:
    matches = regex.findall(s)
    for m in matches: 
        identifier = m[0]
        results[identifier].append(m[0] + m[1])
```

Which gives the following `results`:

```
{'XIC': ['XIC(Switch_A)', 'XIC(Light1)', 'XIC(Light1)', 'XIC(Motor_timer.DN)'],
 'OTE': ['OTE(Light1)', 'OTE(Light2)', 'OTE(Motor)']}
```

Since you have a fixed set of identifiers, you can replace the `[A-Z]{3}` portion of the regex with something that will only match your identifiers:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(XIC|XIO|OTE|TON|TOF)(\([^)]+\))")
```

It is also possible to build this regex if you have your identifiers in an iterable:

```
identifiers = ["XIC", "XIO", "OTE", "TON", "TOF"]
regex = re.compile(rf"({'|'.join(identifiers)})(\([^)]+\))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood you question right:

```py
import re

lst = [
    "XIC(Switch_A)OTE(Light1) XIC(Light1)OTE(Light2) Motor On Delay Timer XIC(Light1)TON(Motor_timer",
    "?",
    "?) XIC(Motor_timer.DN)OTE(Motor)",
]

pat = re.compile(r"[A-Z]+\([^)]+\)")

out = []
for s in lst:
    for val in pat.findall(s):
        out.append(val)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "XIC(Switch_A)",
    "OTE(Light1)",
    "XIC(Light1)",
    "OTE(Light2)",
    "XIC(Light1)",
    "XIC(Motor_timer.DN)",
    "OTE(Motor)",
]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. This is exactly what i was looking for. Now i can further split this into smaller lists for my task